# Laravel in home or public_html

Tags: laravel

Is it recommended to install the laravel framework in the home directory or in the public_html directory. Are there any concerns one should have with either method?

Comment: Laravel 4 or 5? They handle this a little differently (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all up to you.

If you have control over http server, follow these rule:

1. **only** let `<project-root>/public` accessible for public user.
2. Files other than `<project-root>/storage` can be `read` by http server (without `write` permissoin).
3. Only `<project-root>/storage` folder and sub-folder can be `write` by http server.

Answer (score 3):

The ideal scenario is to have your `laravel` app at `home` dir and symlink its `public` folder to `public_html`.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to have your code in your home directory, 1 level up from public_html. Because if you have your app code in public_html (publicly accessible directory), it'll be less secure as compared to the code in your home directory.